# How to ignore "," in data fields

Tags: apache-pig

I am trying to generate following ... 
Input 
396124436476092416,"Think about the life you livin but don't think so hard it hurts Life is truly a gift, but at the same it is a curse",Obey_Jony09
396124440112951296,"00:00 #MAW",WesleyBitton

```
A = LOAD '/user/root/data/tweets.csv' USING PigStorage(',') as (users:chararray, tweets:chararray);
B = FILTER A by users == '396124436476092416';
```

output truncated 
(396124436476092416,"Think about the life you livin but don't think so hard it hurts Life is truly a gift)

Output excepting 
(396124436476092416,"Think about the life you livin but don't think so hard it hurts Life is truly a gift, but at the same it is a curse")

I do not want to read row as line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CSVLoader](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/CSVLoader.html) for loading data

however if you do not wish to do that here is the work around in Apache Pig itself for that :

--Load your Data

```
A  = LOAD 'your/path/users.csv' USING TextLoader() AS (unparsed:chararray);
```

--Replace your `"` string with `|` so as to separate your tweets

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE REPLACE(unparsed, '\\"', '|') AS parsed:chararray;
```

--store your temporary parsed data into your location

```
STORE B INTO 'your/path/parsed_users.csv' USING PigStorage('|');
```

--load your parsed data

```
C = LOAD 'your/path/parsed_users.csv' USING PigStorage('|') AS (users:chararray, tweets:chararray);
```

--Dump your data , how ever this will still contain one extra comma(`,`) but you can replace it by using the replace function you get the point.

```
DUMP C;
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea, changing the ", " into "| " works before filtering. Engine does not have extra value for checking data for these validation function as traditional systems.

Answer (score 0):

Thats fit in the csv [standardization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Standardization), so you need just to use [CSVLoader](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/CSVLoader.html) which

> supports double-quoted fields that contain commas and other
>   double-quotes escaped with backslashes.

This is how to use it :

```
register file:/home/hadoop/lib/pig/piggybank.jar
DEFINE CSVLoader org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVLoader();
A = LOAD '/user/root/data/tweets.csv' USING CSVLoader AS (users:chararray, tweets:chararray); 
B = FILTER A by users == '396124436476092416';
```